# Arrays in PHP (with SOAP)

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, soap

I am trying to output the contents of a web service using SOAP and PHP.

This is the code I have at present:

```
<?php
    $params = array('Criteria' => array( // create "Criteria" array
    'SearchType' => 'sales',
    'MinPrice'=>400000,
    'MinBeds'=>2,
    'MinBaths'=>1,
    'ShowSold' =>true,
    'sortBy'=>'bedrooms',
    'SortDescending'=>true,
    'Limit'=>10,
        'PropertyField'=>array('ID','Image','Address1','Address2','Postcode','PriceString')
    ));
    ?>
    <?php
    // Call the web service function and pass the parameters setup above.
    $featured_properties = $client->call('GetSalesProperties',$params, $ns);
    echo '<div class="results-list">'; 
        foreach ($featured_properties as $featured) {
            echo '<article class="property">' . $featured . '</article>';
        }
    echo '</div>';
    print_r($featured);
    ?>
```

I have added the require_once to initialise the web service and used print_r just to see what should be output. Ideally, I would like the elements in the array to be wrapped in their own tags and each record to be in a containing article.

At the moment, I'm getting **Array** as my echoed content.

My PHP is basic and SOAP is something new so I need help please.

Comment: could you specify clearly what you want & want you are getting

Comment: I'd like a list (limit set as 10) of properties. Each property will have an ID, an image, 3 lines of the address and a price. The elements needed to be wrapped in unique tags ( divs with classes, p and span I guess, for styling.)

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this format for call to add article as root tag,

```
        $featured_propertiest = $client->call('GetSalesProperties', array('article' => $params));
```

And have you declared soap client?

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
$client = new nusoap_client('wsdl_link', true);
```

Comment: I have this in my file:

    require_once('soap/soap.php');

In the soap.php file I have:

    require_once('nusoap.php');
    $client = new nusoap_client('http://myfeed.com/site/webservice.php?wsdl', true);
    $ns = "http://myfeed.com/site/";

I modified your code to this:
    $featured_properties = $client->call('GetSalesProperties', array('article' =>$params), $ns);

All I now get is 114 lines of Array.

Comment: ok, so you want to format your output here. I thought you are having difficulty sending your request to soap server.

Comment: What I want to do is display all the items in the PropertyField array wrapping each item in a unique tag.

Answer (score 0):

OK, getting somewhere and hope this clarifies for others.
Firstly here's a link so you can see what I've been working towards: [Sample Page](http://www.haizdesign.com/soap/)

I have modified my code to this:

```
<?php
    $params = array('Criteria' => array( // create "Criteria" array
    'SearchType' => 'sales',
    'MinPrice'=>400000,
    'MinBeds'=>2,
    'MinBaths'=>1,
    'ShowSold' =>true,
    'sortBy'=>'bedrooms',
    'SortDescending'=>true,
    'Limit'=>2,
    'PropertyField'=>array('ID','Image','Address1','Address2','Postcode','PriceString')
    ));
    ?>
    <?php
    // Call the web service function and pass the parameters setup above.
    $featured_properties = $client->call('GetSalesProperties', $params, $ns);
    echo '<div class="results-list">'; 
        foreach ($featured_properties as $featured) {
        echo '<article class="property">' . 
            '<div class="id">' . $featured['ID'] . '</div>' .
            '<span class="price">' . $featured['PriceString'] . '</span>' .
            '<div class="image">' . $featured['Image'] [1] . '</div>' .
            '<p class="caption">' . $featured['Image'] [1] . '</p>' . 
        '</article>';
        }
    echo '</div>';


    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($featured_properties);
    echo '</pre>';
    ?>
```

I am now getting to my elements and wrapping them in tags for styling.
Not sure how I get to the Image details though and it appears that some images have more than one to display...